# Cannot convert value of type 'String?!' to expected argument type 'Notifications'

Tags: swift

I am trying to check the id of a record before I put it into the array, using `xcode` swift

here is the code. But, i get the following error

> *Notifications.swift:50:46: Cannot convert value of type 'String?!' to expected argument type 'Notifications'*

on this line

```
*if (readRecordCoreData(result["MessageID"])==false)*
```

Please can some one help to explain this error

```
import CoreData

struct Notifications{

var NotifyID = [NSManagedObject]()

  let MessageDesc: String
  let Messageid: String


init(MessageDesc: String, Messageid:String) {

    self.MessageDesc = MessageDesc
   self.Messageid = Messageid
   // self.MessageDate = MessageDate



}

static func MessagesWithJSON(results: NSArray) -> [Notifications] {
    // Create an empty array of Albums to append to from this list

    var Notification = [Notifications]()

    // Store the results in our table data array
    if results.count>0 {

        for result in results {

           //get fields from json

            let Messageid = result["MessageID"] as! String
            let MessageDesc = result["MessageDesc"] as? String

            let newMessages = Notifications(MessageDesc: MessageDesc!, Messageid:Messageid)



            //check with id's from core data
            if (readRecordCoreData(result["MessageID"])==false)
               {

                Notification.append(newMessages)
            }



        }
    }
    return Notification
}

//check id
func readRecordCoreData(Jsonid: String) -> Bool {

    var idStaus = false

    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ItemLog")


    //3
    do {

        let resultsCD = try! managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)



        if (resultsCD.count > 0) {

            for i in 0 ..< resultsCD.count {
                let match = resultsCD[i] as! NSManagedObject
                let id = match.valueForKey("notificationID") as! String

                if (Jsonid as String! == id)
                {
                    idStaus = true

                }
                else{

                    idStaus = false

                }

            }
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    return idStaus

}
```

Comment: I can't see how you'd get *that* error message.  I'd expect you to get an error message about sending `String?` to a method that expect `String`, but there are just so many issues with this code's readability that who knows...

Comment: yes.. sorry grabbed the code from somewhere and added the func. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

One of your methods is static and the other one is not :

```
func readRecordCoreData(Jsonid: String) -> Bool 
static func MessagesWithJSON(results: NSArray) -> [Notifications]
```

Depending on what you want to accomplish you could declare both static, none, or replace

```
 //check with id's from core data
if (readRecordCoreData(result["MessageID"])==false)
{
    Notification.append(newMessages)
}
```

By

```
 //check with id's from core data
if (Notifications.readRecordCoreData(Messageid)==false)
{
    Notification.append(newMessages)
}
```

Not sure if the code will work past compilation however as there are many readability issues